# How do I get box-shadow attribute to work for ReactJS CSS file?

Tags: reactjs

so I was following a tutorial from the freeCodeCamp YouTube channel for ReactJS regarding a project to create a Team Members allocation web app.

Now, I ran into a problem regarding using CSS and React to dynamically group selected members, by highlighting them in a black shadow when a specific group is selected from a drop down list.

From what I understand, an event handler called 'handleEmployeeCardClick' was created to
handle selecting a specific team and highlighting all members of that team in a black shadow-box.

Below is the code for that:

```
function handleEmployeeCardClick(event) {
    const transformedEmployees = employees.map((employee) => employee.id === parseInt(event.currentTarget.id)
      ?(employee.teamName === selectedTeam)?{...employee, teamName:''}   
      :{...employee, teamName: selectedTeam}:employee);
    setEmployees(transformedEmployees);
  }
```

Also the section where the event handler is applied for the html looks like this:

```
 <div class="row justify-content-center mt-3 mb-3">
          <div class="col-8">
           <div class="card-collection">
              {
                employees.map((employee) => (
                  <div id={employee.id} className={(employee.teamName === selectedTeam ? 'card m-2 standout' : 'card m-2')} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={handleEmployeeCardClick}>

                    {(employee.gender === 'male')?<img src={maleProfile} className="card-img-top"/>
                                                 :<img src={femaleProfile} className="card-img-top"/> }
                                                  
                    
                    <div className="card-body">
                      <h5 className="card-title">Full Name: {employee.fullName}</h5>
                      <p className="card-text"><b>Designation:</b>{employee.designation}</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))
              }
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

And the CSS code that manipulates the 'css' file to create the dark shadow looks like this:

```
.standout{
  box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.16) 0px 1px, 4px, rgb(51, 51, 51) 0px 0px 0px 3px; 
}
```

Everything looks fairly correct to me, however I am still not getting the desired output below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEJfT.jpg)

A recreation of the problem is found here [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-glitter-nnn11l?file=/src/App.css)

I am fairly new to React so please forgive me of any newbie errors that seem obvious,
any help is greatly appreciated.
Oh! and the name of the course is called [React JavaScript Framework - ProjectBased Course] by freeCodeCamp released on August 31st, 2022.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You forgot to describe your problem. add more details. it would be even better if you recreate your project on a hosted service such as https://codesandbox.io/ and share the link

Comment: I am using something very similar to (codesandbox.io)  for my project called [link](https://www.replit.com) How do you attach it to my question?

Comment: I am not familiar with replit.com but I imagine you can copy and paste the link to your project.

Comment: @HasanAli, I recreated the problem in [codesandbox.io]. Here's the link [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-glitter-nnn11l?file=/src/App.css). And the objective look is the image I attached in the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have wrong syntax for the box-shadow.  If you open dev console for the page and inspect the cards, they are receiving the `standout` class as expected, and the custom styling is there but it's crossed out because it's being reported as invalid
[image: card debug]

You have an unnecessary comma between the pixel properties that needs to be removed:

```css
.standout{
  box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.16) 0px 1px, 4px, rgb(51, 51, 51) 0px 0px 0px 3px; 
}
```

Should be:

```css
.standout{
  box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.16) 0px 1px 4px, rgb(51, 51, 51) 0px 0px 0px 3px; 
}
```

Comment: No problem.  Please consider upvoting and marking the answer as correct if your problem has been resolved.  Thank you!